# MYSQL + php , avoid date conficts

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with actions such as "Carneval....

```
+-------------------+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
+   Name            +    Date    + action starts + action duration (min) + 
+-------------------+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
+ Carneval          + 2018-04-30 +   12:00:00    +          150          +
+-------------------+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
+ Fairytale evening + 2018-04-30 +   20:00:00    +          200          +
+-------------------+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

How do I avoid puting into database an action like "Eat whatever you can" at 30.04.2018 in 11:58:00 or in 13:00:00?, because those times clearly colide with other actions like Carneval in this example...

I am using PHP to insert data in the table...

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, can you please clarify?

Comment: Id make it simple and have a `action ends` then just do a lookup before. Saves calculating the duration.

Comment: why did you store dates as strings to start with? It'd make your mysql life easier saving as a `DATE` type. Now you have to CAST it. Same goes for your times.

Comment: If you are able to change database, I would go for two `DATETIME` fields `starts_at` and `ends_at`, then you can check if other dates (and times) are `BETWEEN` those or not.

Comment: It is stored as a DATE...
ok i can add a column that have the action status... but it won't help me much.. i can look wheter the action ended, but I want to store that data here even before any action starts.. i wont the script to notify me that two rows are in a conflict...

Comment: Brainfeeder, taht is a good idea... this will help me to do not store the data in between the action duration, but what about when i want to set the time for the new action in 11:58:00... it isn't between 12:00:00 and 14:30:00 but yet it still colides with "Carneval"

Comment: I can clearly say if my action starts when other action is already happening, but what if the actions colide and 2nd one starts sooner that the first one...

Comment: 1. Store the start date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(event_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL 
,start_dt DATETIME NOT NULL 
,end_dt DATETIME NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1, 'Carnival', '2018-04-30 12:00:00','2018-04-30 12:00:00'+INTERVAL 150 MINUTE),
(2, 'Fairytale','2018-04-30 20:00:00','2018-04-30 20:00:00'+INTERVAL 200 MINUTE);


SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
 | event_id | name      | start_dt            | end_dt              |
 +----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
 |        1 | Carnival  | 2018-04-30 12:00:00 | 2018-04-30 14:30:00 |
 |        2 | Fairytale | 2018-04-30 20:00:00 | 2018-04-30 23:20:00 |
 +----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+

INSERT INTO my_table (name,start_dt,end_dt) 
SELECT 'Whatever','2018-04-20 11:58:00','2018-04-30 13:00' 
  FROM (SELECT 1) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.end_dt > '2018-04-30 11:58:00' 
   AND y.start_dt < '2018-04-30 13:00:00' 
 WHERE y.event_id IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
 | event_id | name      | start_dt            | end_dt              |
 +----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
 |        1 | Carnival  | 2018-04-30 12:00:00 | 2018-04-30 14:30:00 |
 |        2 | Fairytale | 2018-04-30 20:00:00 | 2018-04-30 23:20:00 |
 +----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```